# How to debug background notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to debug background push notifications on iOS, and more specifically to set breakpoints into code that should handle a notification to configure internationalized content using custom logic.

I set a breakpoints in my AppDelegate's `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` and `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`.

And I also created a notification service extension and added a breakpoint to its `didReceive(_:withContentHandler:)` because I want to mutate the content of my notification.

When I send the following payload and my app is in the foreground, the breakpoint in `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` gets a hit and everything is fine:

```
{
  "aps" : {
    "badge" : 1012,
    "category" : "GENERIC_MESSAGE",
    "mutable-content" : 1
  },
  "translations" : [
    {
      "LanguageCode" : "fr",
      "Title" : "Aimant détaché",
      "Body" : "L'aimant du capteur 002F51AB, associé à l'outil HT-1225 Hitachi Tas, a été détaché."
    },
    {
      "LanguageCode" : "en",
      "Body" : "The magnet of the tag 002F51AB, link to tool HT-1225 Hitachi Tas, was detached.",
      "Title" : "Magnet detached"
    },
    {
      "LanguageCode" : "nl",
      "Body" : "De magneet van de tag 002F51AB, gelinkt aan het gereedschap HT-1225 Hitachi Tas, is losgekoppeld.",
      "Title" : "Magneet losgekoppeld"
    }
  ],
  "messageId" : "90073ebb-ce51-ea11-a94c-000d3a213771"
}
```

But if the application is in the background and I send the exact same notification, I don't get a hit on `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`. Same thing when I run the notification service extension, I don't get a hit in `didReceive(_:withContentHandler:)`

Am I forgetting something? Is it because my notification payload doesn't have an aps alert field?

Comment: If your app is in the background then notifications are generally delivered to the user, not to your app.  The exception here is silent push notifications, which will resume (or relaunch) your app in the background so that it can process the notification.

Comment: So what should I do to have this push notification always delivered to my app? How do I make it a silent push notification?

Comment: As a general piece of advice, I find [Unified Logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) to be invaluable for debugging an app when I’m not attached to the debugger, but want to watch log device events on my macOS console. For things like push notifications, background sessions, etc., it’s really use to diagnose when not attached to the debugger (because that alters an app’s lifecycle). See WWDC 2016 video [Unified Logging and Activity Tracing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: when I add an alert field to my push notification, even with a dummy string, then it get forwarded to my Notification Service. Otherwise it doesn't.